# CSS: Multiple Attribute Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to style form inputs of type "email" and "password", but not anything else. I was imagining something like the following:

```
input[type="email"][type="password"] {
    ....
}
```

However, the way attribute selectors work, it appears to interpret this as "input where the type is simultaneously both 'email' *and* 'password'". What I'm going for is "input where the type is either exactly 'email' *or* 'password'". Of course, nothing is both of type email and of type password at the same time.

Is it possible to write a CSS rule that *or*'s across multiple different attribute selectors?

For reference, the HTML would look something like:

```
<form id="login" onsubmit="return fadeaway()">
    <fieldset>
    <input type="email" placeholder="username"/> <br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/> <br />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct: combining simple selectors like this does an AND operation on all of them for each given element.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just do this:

```
input[type="email"], input[type="password"]
```

Comment: Perhaps the single permutation of commas, spaces, brackets, and ordering that I did not try....

Answer (score 4):

use a comma :

```
input[type="email"],input[type="password"] {
    ....
}
```

[w3 docs on group selectors here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping)